# Swift - Is there a way to remove data from API that doesn't contain a certain key?

Tags: swift, api, data-structures

I am using Tasty recipes/list API from (https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/tasty/).

Unfortunately, this API is a mess (but it is the only one I could find that allows you to search for recipes by keyword and return a list of ingredients and instructions. As well as have a response time of under 8 seconds).

When I do a search it will either return a list of recipes or an item with a list of recipes. I am just trying to retrieve a list of recipes (and remove the ones that contain a list). I've found that the data I want contains a list of 50 items while the ones I do not want contain 28 items.

So would there be a way to check how many items that piece of data has and remove it from the list of data I am retrieving?

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Response: Decodable, Encodable {
    let results: [Data]
}

struct Data: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let name: String
    let thumbnail_url: String
    let sections: [Section]
    let instructions: [Instruction]
    let num_servings: Int
    let prep_time_minutes: Int?
    let cook_time_minutes: Int?
    let total_time_minutes: Int?
}

struct Section: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let components: [Ingredient]
}

struct Ingredient: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let raw_text: String
}

struct Instruction: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let display_text: String
}
```

I can provide more info/code upon request. Thank you I appreciate it!

Here is a picture of the data it returns (from the RapidAPI link above)

[image: data]

Comment: You should filter on `count` being 50 but I have no idea from reading your question what array you want to filter on

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would need to filter the `results` array to check if each instance has a count of 50 or 28. Do you know how I would do that with this data structure?

Comment: What is each instance here, do you have an array of `Response` or do you want to filter on something inside `Data`? Maybe you could add a simple example?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `results` contains an array of `Data`. I need to filter the `results` to check if each instance of `Data` contains a count of 50 or 28. Basically something like this: `results.filter{Data.count < 28}`. I don't know how to get that line to work

Comment: You are not making any sense. `results` is an array but an instance of `Data` is not an array so it has no `count`. So for the last time, what is it you want to count?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is right: can you at least provide a sample of the JSON that you receive, showing what data you want to see and what you want to exclude?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hmm. The API returns an array of `results`. Each instance of `results` either contains an array of 50 items or 28 items. I need to filter the `results` so that it only contains an array of items which hold 50 items in their array.

Comment: Something like `let filtered = responses.filter { $0.count == 50 }` then where `responses` is an array of `Response` and $0 in the filter closure is the `responses` array. Or if you have a single `Response` then you simply approve (or disregard) the whole result based on the count of `results`, `if response.results.count == 50 {...`

Comment: With that image I finally understand what you mean, the 50 and 28 you are talking about are not arrays but they are json dictionaries where the count is the number of key/value pairs in the dictionary which turns this into a completely different question and without knowing what the difference is between the 28 and the 50 count dictionaries I can't really help you.

Comment: Does your decoding using the types in the question work fine?

Comment: Is there a way to filter based on if the dictionary has a certain key?

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question but I think this could be done with a custom  `init(from:)` in `Response` that check each item in `results` array. You could do it with JSONSerialization that creates a dictionary that you could filter but it is not as clean as handling this with `Codable`

Comment: Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: No because I am kind of guessing what to do since there isn’t enough information to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson . I just wish this API returned one type of data instead of two... I'll message the owner of the API asking if they can fix that